# Find a certain string and replace it in a nested JObject?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON object where I would like to search for the string: "Customer.CustomerAddress.Common" and replace it with "Customer.CustomerAddress.Common.S2" wherever it is present i.e. at all occurrences.  How can this be done?

```
 {
   "$id": "1",
   "$type": "Customer.CustomerAddress, Customer.CustomerAddress.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4",
   "FlatRate": 29.65,
   "AmountFinanced": 12402.2,
   "AmountUsed": 12302.2,
   "TotalPayment": 0,
   "CustomerAddress": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.CustomerAddress.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "Items": {
         "$id": "3",
         "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.CustomerAddress.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
         "$values": []
      },
      "Added": {
         "$id": "4",
         "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.CustomerAddress.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
         "$values": []
      },
      "Removed": {
         "$id": "5",
         "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.CustomerAddress.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
         "$values": []
      }
   }
   }
```

Comment: [JSON.NET has some of the better documentation out there, with lots of samples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm#!). Please show what research you've done, and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We go through all the descendants, find properties with the desired name and value, then replace the value with the desired one.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var json = JObject.Parse(text);

var props = json.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "$type" &&
        p.Value.ToString().Contains("Customer.CustomerAddress.Common"));

foreach (var p in props)
{
    p.Value = p.Value.Value<string>()
        .Replace("Customer.CustomerAddress.Common", "Customer.CustomerAddress.Common.S2");
}

File.WriteAllText("result.json", json.ToString());
```